# Check for multiple occurrences of a character in string

Tags: regex

I'm struggling with what should be somewhat simple.
I need to make a regex to check if a string is valid.
One of the criteria is that the string only contains 1 period ('.').

So, I'm having problems making a match, that will go off if it finds a single period, multiple times. It is not periods standing next to eachother (`\.{2,}`) but single periods, at multiple locations in my string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this expression `\..*\.` matches, then the string contains more than 1 period...

Comment: Or, `\.[^.]*\.`.  To check for more than two occurrences: ``\.([^.]*\.){n-1}``, i.e. 6 or more will look like ``\.([^.]*\.){5}`` (or ``\.(?:[^.]*\.){5}`` or ``\.(?:.*?\.){5}``)